# Rbind to csv file in R

Tags: r

There is a csv file stored in R project folder as shown below

df.csv

```
Cola  Colb   Colc
 A     GF     34
 S     FD     34
 D     FS     32
```

Scenario 1 : I do have dataframe in R  (With same columns)

```
df1
Cola  Colb   Colc
 F     DW      43
```

Is there a way to append this to csv
Expected output

```
Cola  Colb   Colc
 A     GF     34
 S     FD     34
 D     FS     32
 F     DW     43
```

Scenario 2 : I do have dataframe in R  (With extra columns)

```
df1
Cola  Colb   Colc    Cold
 F     DW      43     48
```

Can we append this to csv

Expected output

```
Cola  Colb   Colc  Cold
 A     GF     34    NA
 S     FD     34    NA
 D     FS     32    NA
 F     DW     43    48
```

So basically even if there are same number of columns or different, still append should happen with NA values

Comment: have you tried `rbind`, `dplyr::bind_rows` or even `data.table::rbindlist`?

Comment: i need to append the csv without reading it so :)

Comment: If you can't read it then you first need to match the columns, so you can use `writeLines`.

Comment: Then use a tool like [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv)

Comment: `write.table()` has an `append`-argument

Comment: If you do not want to read the csv, but only append data (put it at the end).. then how do you think to be able to fill new columns?

Comment: Yeah we can put at the end. Right

Comment: @Wimpel how do we do this :) ? write.table should have same number of column

Comment: correct. As far as I know, there is no way to append new rows in combination with filled columns without reading the .csv first.